# Result not repeatable for Thread Interrupt in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupt-handling

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        CounterThread ct = new CounterThread();
        ct.setDaemon(true);
        ct.start();

        ct.join(2);

        System.out.println("interrupt status: " + ct.getState()); // key sentence
        if (ct.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("start interrupt");
            ct.interrupt();
        }

        System.out.println("result: " + ct.getResult());

    }
}

class CounterThread extends Thread {

    private int result;

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
            if (i == 999999998) {
                result = 5;
                System.out.println("calculate finished");
            }
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                result = -1;
                System.out.println("receive interrupt signal");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the code above to test java interrupt mechanism. When I comment out the print sentence

> System.out.println("interrupt status: " + ct.getState());

the result is always the same as:

start interrupt
receive interrupt signal
result: -1

While I leave it in the code, the result is NOT repeatable. The result can be:

interrupt status: RUNNABLE
start interrupt
result: -1
receive interrupt signal

Or:

interrupt status: RUNNABLE
start interrupt
result: 0
receive interrupt signal

Can't figure out the reason, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation has a race condition and it is just a coincidence that you had repeatable result with commented out `System.out.println("interrupt status: " + ct.getState());` line. The issue is that threads are running in parallel and there is no guarantee that statement `result = -1;` in `CounterThread` is executed before `System.out.println("result: " + ct.getResult());` in the main thread.

To make the result repeatable you need to wait until the following block is executed:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    result = -1;
    System.out.println("receive interrupt signal");
    return;
}
```

You can achieve it by adding `join()` call before printing the result.

```
ct.join();
System.out.println("result: " + ct.getResult());
```

In that case the main thread will wait until `CounterThread` is finished and print the result.